# Unable to submit the MudTextField value after hit enter key in MudBlazor

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have **MudForm** with *MudTextField* inside my **blazor webassembly** application and i would like to send the bound value from the text field when the user **hit the Enter key**.
Here is what i have tried but when i listen for enter key the bound value is always null

```
<MudForm Class="d-flex flex-grow-1 px-4" SubmitOnEnter="true">
            <MudTextField T="string" Placeholder="@Localizer["Enter your message..."]" @bind-Value="@MyChatState.CurrentMessage"
                          DisableUnderLine="true" Lines="2" Margin=Margin.Dense Clearable="true"
                          Variant="Variant.Outlined" Validation="@(_validator.ValidateFieldsAsync)" OnKeyDown="HandleKeyDown" />
```

```
@code {
        protected async Task HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == "Enter")
            {
                var message = MyChatState.CurrentMessage //this message is always null
                
               //Send the message to the API 
            }
        }
               
}
```

Comment: Use `Immediate="true"` on the `MudTextField`.